# Directory contents not fully copied by scp command

Tags: windows-10, scp, debian-buster

I'm running Windows 10, and the server is on Debian 10 and I'm copying a [Svelte](https://svelte.dev) build directory from my computer to a remote server. I'm using the command to copy the files:

```
scp -r ./build user@remote.host:~/directory
```

But there are some files (and entire directories) consistently left out and I end up having to go through and manually copying them over.

Remote directory.

[image: Screenshot.]

Local directory; the entire `(play)` directory is dropped.

[image: Screenshot.]

I tried running it with the verbose argument, but it didn't tell me anything special (I think). Why is it doing this, and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally use SCP for transferring one file at a time. Or just files matching a pattern from a specific directory. Never for copying a full directory structure

For cases like that, I would use Rsync instead. For example, here is your command translated to an Rsync equivalent:

```
rsync -avzh ./build user@remote.host:~/directory
```

Try it out. It should work.

Comment: Hey! Downvoteders! My answer was posted *after* the original poster indicated that my recommendation of `rsync -avzh ./build user@remote.host:~/directory` should work and they confirmed it did indeed work.

Answer (score 1):

I think that SCP needs a directory structure to exist on the remote server. It will not create folders.

You can use `-e` flag with rsync, to use a remote shell to carry out the transfer.

```
rsync -r -e "ssh -p 222" /home/test/dev user@0.0.0.0:/home/remotetest/dev
```

Comment: Why are you using `ssh -p 222`? That is port 222 which is non-standard; it is typically port `22` which doesn’t need a `-p` designation? PS: My answer was posted *after* the original poster indicated that my recommendation of `rsync -avzh ./build user@remote.host:~/directory` should work and they confirmed it did indeed work.